# How to use a dictionary to modify an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I am trying to use a dictionary (created by reading the content of a first file) to modify the content of an array(created by reading the content of a second file) in order to return as many modified arrays as their are keys in the dictionary with the modification corresponding the position and change in the original array indicated in the values for each key.

From a minimal example, if my dictionary and my list are:

```
change={'change 1': [(1, 'B'), (3, 'B'), (5, 'B'), (7, 'B')], 'change 2': [(2, 'B'), (4, 'B'), (6, 'B')]}
s=['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Then, I would like my code to return two lists:

```
['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']
```

I tried to code this in python3:

```
change={'change 1': [(1, 'B'), (3, 'B'), (5, 'B'), (7, 'B')], 'change 2': [(2, 'B'), (4, 'B'), (6, 'B')]}
s=['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
for key in change:
    s1=s
    for n in change[key]:
        s1[n[0]-1] = n[1]
    print(key, s1)
    print(s)
```

However it seems that even if I am only modifying the list `s1` which is a copy of `s`, I am nontheless modifying `s` as well, as it returns:

```
change 1 ['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
change 2 ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

So although I get the first list right, the second isn't and I don't understand why.

Could you help me see what is wrong in my code, and how to make it work?
Many thanks!

Comment: `s1` isn't a *copy* of `s`, it *is* `s`.  The two variables are different names for the same object.  Do `s1 = s.copy()` if you want it to be a copy.

Comment: In python, "Assignment never copies data". You might be interested in this talk: https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns (Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values, Ned Batchelder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `s1` isn't a copy of `s`, it's just another name for `s`.

I'd suggest doing this by just building a new list in a comprehension, e.g.:

```
>>> change={'change 1': [(1, 'B'), (3, 'B'), (5, 'B'), (7, 'B')], 'change 2': [(2, 'B'), (4, 'B'), (6, 'B')]}
>>> s=['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

```
>>> for t in change.values():
...     d = dict(t)
...     print([d.get(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(s, 1)])
...
['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']
```

But if you change your original code to initialize `s1` to `s.copy()` it seems to work:

```
>>> for key in change:
...     s1 = s.copy()
...     for n in change[key]:
...         s1[n[0]-1] = n[1]
...     print(s1)
...
['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure a copy of an instance of a class with all its dependencies is completely being copied, use `deepcopy` as follows:

```
import copy 
change={'change 1': [(1, 'B'), (3, 'B'), (5, 'B'), (7, 'B')], 'change 2': [(2, 'B'), (4, 'B'), (6, 'B')]}
s=['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
for key in change:
    s1=copy.deepcopy(s)
    for n in change[key]:
        s1[n[0]-1] = n[1]
    print(key, s1)
    print(s)
```